# php - Include different file if site is accessed using https

Tags: php, file, https, include

I have site which has installed ssl certificate but it can be accessed also without it.
Till now i have used:             on my pages but now i need to have some option to show different file if site has been accessed using https. Example:
If using http: to show         if using https: to show        instead.

Is this possible?
Thank you for any reply.
Gent.

Comment: Do <?php print_r($_SERVER); ?> in both cases and you'll learn more

Answer (score 3):

You can check for https with

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) AND $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    include("file1.php");
}
else {
    include("file2.php");
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` is not set when none SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if [$_SERVER['HTTPS']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is non-empty:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    include 'https.php';
else
    include 'http.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing via HTTPS, $_SERVER['HTTPS'] should be set (although this depends on server config).

You can also check which port is being used:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']==443){
}
```

Neither of these works in every possible config  (for example behind load balancers) but they should work in straightforward setups.

Comment: wow.. thank you guys.. i was still trying to edit my post and you added very helping answers... You are awesome :).. I will try right now :)